# Entering Data to a HashMap Dynamically

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I was wondering how to properly (or even if you can) add data to a `HashMap` like an `ArrayList`?

So I have a function, which checks the entered string for commas and separates the values, adds them into an `ArrayList` and then stores the `ArrayList` keyed against the name of the field they were entering data to:

```
ArrayList<String> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
Map<String, ArrayList<String>> dataMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();
String[] parts;
public void CheckForMultipleEntries(String field, String data){
    dataList.clear();
    if(data.contains(",")){
        data.replace("", "");
        parts = data.split(",");
        for(String part : parts){
            dataList.add(part);
        }
        dataMap.put(field, dataList);
    }

    System.out.println(dataMap);
    System.out.println(dataMap.get("test"));
}
```

However say first for `"Header"` I enter `"test1, test2, test3"` - this will enter & output correctly (as: `{Header=[test1, test2, test3]}`) but if for the next value I then enter, say, `"Body"` `"test4, test5, test6"` then when I output the map I get `{Header=[test4, test5, test6], Body=[test4, test5, test6]}`.

Why is it overwriting the values, but not the keys? And how do I fix it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Read the accepted answer of the linked question. (Topic "Adding the Same Object")

Comment: Btw `data.replace("", "");` does nothing.

Comment: I know - in the actual code its .repalce(" ", ""); - don't know why it came across like that

Comment: That won't do anything either.

Comment: How so? Its getting rid of the whitespace, no?

Comment: You need to re-read what `replace` does and think about the question "does it actually change the current string?".

Comment: Yes, it does actually change the current string, in the way I expected and wanted (to get rid of whitespace), so what exactly do you mean it wont do anything?

Comment: Sorry, but "Yes, it does actually change the current string" is a blantant lie. Strings are immutable and it ___can't___ change the String. The documentation even says so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182780/discussion-between-aristotletheaxolotl-and-tom).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Value is getting overidden because, you are using

```
dataList.clear();
```

you are putting the reference of arraylist `dataList` in the hashmap. so you have to re initialize the arraylist evertime you allot with new values

replacing `dataList.clear();`  with  `dataList=new ArrayList<>();` will solve your issue

Comment: Haha crap you're right. I feel so foolish for not spotting this. I forgot its storing the actual ArrayList and not just the values inside. How can I change this so I can do what I want? Edit: Just saw the edit you made to your answer. Thank you

Comment: replace dataList.clear(); with  dataList=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Welcome @AristotleTheAxolotl

Answer (score 0):

Smth. like that. Do not forget, that each map key have it's own `List`:

```
public static void add(Map<String, List<String>> map, String key, String value) {
    map.computeIfAbsent(key, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(value);
}
```